# Can the verb "hinder" be used to describe good things?

Tags: verbs

I am searching words for making it difficult for something to do, and found the verb "hinder", which is defined in LONGMAN dictionary as follows with some examples:

> [to make it difficult for something to develop or succeed](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/hinder)
>
> [His career has been hindered by injury.](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/hinder)
>
> [policies that will hinder rather than help families](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/hinder)

It seems that this word is usually used to describe bad things. Can this be used to describe good things, for example, as follows?

> Painting a wooden door will hinder degradation of the door.

Comment: You mean to stop bad things from happening, right? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hinder simply means to make it difficult for something to develop or succeed. In itself the word is neither negative nor positive. What is hindered can be a good, neutral, or bad thing. It is good if vaccination hinders the spread of a disease, but bad if police slowness hinders the fight against crime.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use "hinder degradation" It is rare, but here is an example: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15046348

Similarly there are examples of "Hinder decay" http://orbit.dtu.dk/en/publications/matrix-changes-and-side-effects-induced-by-electrokinetic-treatment-of-porous-and-particulate-materials(e2b50eb8-325f-4c2a-ac0c-4b05aa410074).html

> Transport of ions in an applied electric field holds many applications[... E.g.] for desalination of porous stone materials to hinder decay.

"Hinder" and "degradation" are already fairly rare words, and in this context is it limited to a formal context.  "to prevent degradation" or "to slow degradation" are possible alternatives.

Comment: For some reasons, I don't want to use the word "prevent".  Is it appropriate to use "restrain" or "inhibit"  instead of "hinder" in my example sentence?

Comment: Hinder isn't very rare, it is fairly rare and is normally in an at least moderately formal context.  You also can [edit] if you spot spelling mistakes.

Comment: Fairly rare, moderately formal. Sounds like my native head space.